# How do check if a list contains an item without calculating the entire list? Python 3.6

Tags: python, list, permutation

I am new to programming and don't know if this is doable.

Basically, I have a big list. I want to find a certain object in this list. If I do find that object, then I am not interested in the remaining list, at this point we just break the iteration. Is this doable without first having Python calculate all the elements in the list?

The list is a permutation of size n of a list of size m > n. I can use itertool.permutation to get this list of permutations, and then use a for loop to iterate through the entire list, but this requires that I calculate each permutation (could be huge if m >> n >> 1). Is there any way to create each permutation during each iteration?

```
for i in length of permutation:
    create ith element in permutation
    see if it satisfies our property
        if yes
             return True
```

Comment: `itertools.permutations` is a generator, so as long as you dont do `list(perms)` you aren't actually generating the entire list. Only the next element is generated each iteration, the entire list of all permutations is never generated and stored in memory unless you explicitly force python to do that by using `list()`.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Comment: I don't even know what a generator is. Sounds really cool. I will look it up. thx.

Comment: Technically, the result of `itertools.permutations` is *not* a generator, although, it behaves the same as a generator in the respect that it is evaluated lazily. Try `isinstance(p, types.GeneratorType)` where `p` is the result of some call to `itertools.permutations`

Comment: This is the default behaviour of the `in` operator.  If you have a more complex criterion you can use the `any` and `map` functions which are also lazily evaluated.

Comment: Are you checking properties on the items themselves, or does the check depend on its position in the permutation?

Comment: I needed the clarification to see if you could benefit from filtering the list, then doing the permutation.